# scatter graph with dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am working with excel an a scatter graph. I have a full table of data but want to dynamically filter the data for the range based on values in associated columns in the table. Take for example the following:

https://uploadpie.com/Ofzfxa

So from the above, I only want the x and y, for the rows that have Name John in Month April. I am trying to include syntax for this to be dynamically filtered so could change name or month easily.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score -1):

Use a pivot table. Then make a pivot chart from the pivot table. You can use the built in filters.

If you are trying to change your x and y axis range based on the x & y columns. I'm not sure this will solve that.